# Draw specific polygon and select points within

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, arcgis-10.5

My goal is to select the points that are inside a rectangle.

How do I create a rectangle with 100 meter width and then only select and extract the points that fall inside?

I'm using ArcMap 10.5.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a polygon feature class. While drawing the polygon, right-click and choose 'length' to enter your dimensions. Selections can only be made from within a polygon (so you cannot draw a 'line'rectangle). Use the Selection tab at the top of arcmap page to 'Select by Location'. Enter your points layer as the' target' and your rectangle(polygon) layer as the 'source' . Set the spatial method to 'are within the source layer' and click 'Ok'. The points will be highlighted.You can then right-click your points layer from within the Table of Contents and hit 'data' then 'export data' . In the export dialog window , ensure you are exporting only the selected features and click 'ok'.

Comment: Thank you, I can draw the polygon now, but it then becomes part of the shape file layer? 

I think the best would be to create a new shape file with specific dimensions so I can then match the points to that. How would that work?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the Draw toolbar and select the polygon tab(fourth icon from left) to draw your polygon. Afterwards, from the Selection tab at the top of the arcmap page, choose to 'select by graphics'. This will select/highlight all the points inside your polygon. You can then export the selected points .

Comment: thank you but how can I specify specific dimensions with the draw tool?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this site to create polygons:
http://gis.ucla.edu/apps/click2shp/

And Shaniceb approach for exporting the relevant data.